# Google Sheets API read cells (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets

My goal is simply to read cells in a Google sheet of my account and display them in a html block of a Wordpress website so that anyone can see the values of the cells.

I have set up a "service account" on *console.developers.google.com*, and my code is the following, but it doesn't work :

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

        function loadSheetsAPI() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('my-api-key');
            var discoveryUrl =
            'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';
            gapi.client.load(discoveryUrl).then(getCounter);
        }

        function getCounter() {
            gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
              spreadsheetId: 'my-sheet-id',
              range: '!H2:I2',
            }).then(function(response) {
              var range = response.result;
              if (range.values.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
                  var row = range.values[i];
                  appendPre(row[1] + '\n' + row[0]);
                }
              } else {
                appendPre('No data found');
              }
            }, function(response) {
              appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
            });
          }

        function appendPre(message) {
            var pre = document.getElementById('output');
            var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
            pre.appendChild(textContent);
          }

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadSheetsAPI">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<pre id="output"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: [And the error is...](http://s266.photobucket.com/user/jobstran/media/drumroll.gif.html)

Comment: @Adelin Yep, what is my "error" ? lol

Comment: I'm working through the same problem right now -- will update once i find a solution

Comment: OK -- so go to the developer console and search for the sheets api and look at how it works. They currently DO NOT OFFER a way to access data via a key. unfortunately. the two ways are service account api and oauth2

Comment: have you looked at the following ? https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/03/04/accessing-google-spreadsheets-from-node-js/

Comment: I will look at it thanks, but I would like to find a solution in Javascript to embed it in a html block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i use Sheets2Table wordpress plugin and it does the job. Thanks to the author of this plugin :)